# Rails 4 - Nested form with accepts_nested_attributes_for controller setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to make a nested form with `form_for` and `fields_for`. After much research and in-success, not working on my project anymore. I'm just trying to recreate a railscast to see what have I done wrong.

I'm trying to re-create the example found at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 which shouldn't be that hard since the code is there, but I can't manage to create questions from the survey. Here is my code until now:

```
rails new surveysays
rails g scaffold survey name:string
rake db:migrate
rails g scaffold question survey_id:integer content:text
rake db:migrate
```

I'm trying to do in the exact same sequence of the video.
My Question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

My Survey model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

My survey form with nested questions fields:

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
      ...
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
        <p>
          <%= builder.label :content, "Question" %><br/>
          <%= builder.text_area :content, :row => 3 %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
```

My survey show:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @survey.name %>
</p>

<ol>
  <% for question in @survey.questions %>
   <li><%=h question.content%></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_survey_path(@survey) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', surveys_path %>
```

And my SurveysController:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
 ...

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times { @survey.questions.build }
  end

 ...

  # POST /surveys
  # POST /surveys.json
  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  ...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_survey
       @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
       params.require(:survey).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

As until min 5:34 and thats when it doesn't work as shown in the video and doesn't create the questions, the form appears with the 3 questions, I fill the form, but when a press <kbd>create</kbd> it doesn't create the questions:

Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
   2.1.3 :001 > s = Survey.all
     Survey Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "surveys".* FROM "surveys"
     => #]> 
   2.1.3 :002 > q = s[0].questions
     Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."survey_id" = ?      [["survey_id", 2]]
     => #

I can't see any difference between my code and the example. I even tried to make some alterations in the `SurveysController` without any success:

Inserting question_attributes:[:id ,:content] in permit of method survey_params
or 
Inserting @survey.questions.create(survey_params[:questions_attributes]) after if survey.save on create method, this creates the question but with content: nill

At this point I am stuck. I don't know what more what to do, what am I missing int the controller?
Can anyone give me some help, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

On the `survey_params` method in the controller, you are missing the question params, it should look like:

```
def survey_params
 params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :questions_attributes => [:question, :answer ... or whatever attribute for the question model])
end
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you very much, yes i found it a bit ago, I was actually coming here to answer my post. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The survey_params needs to change to permit the nested attributes, from:

```
def survey_params
   params.require(:survey).permit(:name)
end
```

to:

```
def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [:id , :content])
end
```

Comment: `questions_attributes: [:id , :content, :_destroy]` may be a better fit if destroying associations is also required.