# Rails 5 accepts_nested_attributes_for unpermitted parameter error? (React front end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have looked at previous SO solutions on `accepts_nested_attributes` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682951/rails-4-nested-form-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-controller-setup), but I am still getting the error. I am using React as front end and Rails back end. I am trying to create a request to be sent to schedules, and from there to populate to workers.

I am using Rails 5.0.2. I have a `schedule, worker, roster` models.

```
//Schedule
  has_many :workers, through: :rosters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rosters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers #implement accept_nested_attributes here

//Roster
  belongs_to :schedule
  belongs_to :worker

//Worker
  has_many :schedules, through: :rosters
  has_many :rosters
```

And here is my Schedule controller:

```
  def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save
      render json: @schedule
    else
      render json: @schedule, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  ...


private

  def schedule_params
    params.permit(:date, :user_id, :workers_attributes => [:worker_id, :name, :phone])
  end
```

Here is the error that I got:

```
app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:13:in `create'
Started POST "/api/schedules" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-23 10:30:38 -0700
Processing by SchedulesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1, "workers_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Iggy Test", "phone"=>"1
23-456-7890"}, "schedule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1}}
Unpermitted parameter: schedule
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Why is my request shows `Unpermitted parameter schedule`? If I remove `workers_attributes` and only have `params.permit(:date, :user_id)`, it works. I can't figure out why the error points to schedule. How can I make successful POST nested_attributes request to rails?

I am using fetch to do POST request from react side:

```
...
return fetch(`api/schedules`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      date: date,
      user_id: 1,
      workers_attributes: {name: "Iggy Test", phone: "123-456-7890"}
    })
```

**EDIT:**

After following answer from @gabrielhilal, I added `require()`: `params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :user_id, :workers_attributes => [:id, :name, :phone])`, and edited the fetch POST on React's end to have array of objects instead of plain objects: `workers_attributes: [{name: "Iggy Test", phone: "123-456-7890"}]`. It does not complain anymore, and it *does* register new schedule. However, new workers are all `nil`:

```
#Worker.last shows:
 #<Worker id: 32, name: nil, phone: nil, created_at: "2017-05-23 19:36:09", updated_at: "2017-05-23 19:36:09">
```

Sorry, don't mean to create nested question, but does anyone know why it is nil?

**EDIT 2:**

I got it to work, sort of.

If I have

```
def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    @workers = @schedule.rosters.build.build_worker
...
```

and

```
//schedule_params
params.permit(:date, :user_id, :workers_attributes => [:id, :name, :pho
```

ne])

I was able to have `"Iggy Test"` to display, but it immediately creates another `nil` worker.

Log:

```
Started POST "/api/schedules" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-23 20:42:38 -0700
Processing by SchedulesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1, "workers_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"Iggy Test", "phone"=>"
123-456-7890"}], "schedule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1}}
Unpermitted parameter: schedule
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "schedules" ("date", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["date", 20
17-05-26 02:00:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["user_id", 1]
]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "workers" ("name", "phone", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Iggy
Test"], ["phone", "123-456-7890"], ["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "rosters" ("worker_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["worker_id", 56], ["c
reated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "workers" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC
], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "rosters" ("schedule_id", "worker_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["sc
hedule_id", 52], ["worker_id", 57], ["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "rosters" SET "schedule_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "rosters"."id" = ?  [["schedule_id", 52],
["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:42:38 UTC], ["id", 52]]
   (5.6ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 417ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
```

If I modified params to have require(:schedule)

```
params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :user_id, :workers_attributes => [:id, :name, :phone])
```

It creates a `nil` worker only.

Log:

```
Started POST "/api/schedules" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-23 20:45:03 -0700
Processing by SchedulesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1, "workers_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"Iggy Test", "phone"=>"
123-456-7890"}], "schedule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schedules" ("date", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["date", 20
17-05-26 02:00:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC], ["user_id", 1]
]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "workers" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC
], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC]]

  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "rosters" ("schedule_id", "worker_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["sc
hedule_id", 53], ["worker_id", 58], ["created_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-24 03:45:03 UTC]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post:

```
{
  "date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z",
  "user_id"=>1,
  "workers_attributes"=>{
    "name"=>"Iggy Test",
    "phone"=>"123-456-7890"
  },
  "schedule"=> {
    "date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z",
    "user_id"=>1
  }
}
```

You have two issues:

- `schedule` is not permitted (that's why you see the message in the logs), but it will be just ignored anyway (won't raise any error).
- the `workers_attributes` should be a collection of workers and not a simple hash, so that's why you are having the error.

You should get something like the following in the post request:

```
{
  "date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z",
  "user_id"=>1,
  "workers_attributes"=>{
    "0" => {
      "name"=>"Iggy Test",
      "phone"=>"123-456-7890"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @gabrielhilal, your answer helped to fix one problem - thanks!! I added `require()` in my params method, now I have: `params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :user_id, :workers_attributes => [:id, :name, :phone])`. It fixes the `schedule` error. I also changed my POST request for `workers_attributes` into array of objects: `workers_attributes: [{name: "Iggy Test", phone: "123-456-7890"}]`. One problem, is when I do `Worker.last`, it shows `nil` attributes: `<Worker id: 32, name: nil, phone: nil, created_at: "2017-05-23 19:36:09", updated_at: "2017-05-23 19:36:09">`. Do you know why?

Comment: looking at your `params` I don't think you need the `params.require(:schedule)` unless you are sending everything inside `schedule`, such as `{"schedule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-25T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1,  "workers_attributes"=>{...}}}`...

Comment: When I removed it, it does not make any difference to the final result/ what's saved in DB. `Worker.last` still shows `nil` for both name and phone. It seems like Rails did not realize the parameters are there. Newly created Worker only has `id`, `updated_at` and `created_at`.

Comment: Try to print the schedule_params

Comment: `puts schedule_params.inspect` gives: `<ActionController::Parameters {"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1} permitted: true>`

Comment: I sort of got it to work. See edit 2 part, after following your suggestion :)