# Rails 5 Nested Resources for 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, erb

I have 3 models:

**Report**

```
has_many :report_items, dependent: :destroy

has_many :items, through: :report_items
```

**Item**

```
has_many :report_items, dependent: :destroy

has_many :reports, through: :report_items
```

**ReportItem**

```
belongs_to :item

belongs_to :report
```

I scaffolded all 3 models so now I have 3 separate views for each.

Right now if I wanted to assign an item to a report, I have to:

1. Create new Item record
2. Create new Report record
3. Create new ReportItem record, using the id's of Item and Report to tie them together.

However what I need is for **ReportItem** to be nested inside **Report**. The idea is that after I create a new report, I can go to its "show" page and create "report_items" records from there. These  "report_items" records automatically use the current "report" record's id.

I've gone to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to research on how this would work. However, I'm still confused as to how to actually accomplish it.

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.
In you **report** create form,

```
<%= simple_form_for(@report) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :title %>

  <%= form.simple_fields_for(:report_items) do |ri_form| %>
    <%= ri_form.input :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Then, Your **Report** model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_items
```

In your `ReportController`, get the nested attributes:

```
private
def report_params
 params.require(:report).permit(:name, :report_items_attributes => [:name])
end
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682951/rails-4-nested-form-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-controller-setup) answer for better view.
[Here](http://blog.biasedwalk.com/2013/06/acceptsnestedattributesfor-on-hasmany.html) is a good tutorial.

**EDITED**

Seems like you've created a new Report and then go the show page. In show page you want to create Report Item. So, when you go to the show page, the current url must contains the current `report_id`. All you need is `Item_id`. You can load all the **items** with IDs and create a dropdown to select the `item_id`. Then in the show page, `report_item` may look like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@report_item) do |form| %>
  # in the current page @report contains the current report object  
  <%= form.input :report_id, as: hidden, value: @report.id %>
  # @items = Item.all
  <%= form.input :item_id, collection: @items, label_method: :item_name, value_method: :id, label: "Item", include_blank: false, selected: @report.item_id %>

  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>


<% end %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Emu! Thank you for your answer. However it is not what I had in mind. I have edited my question for clarity.