# How can I insert many records from Controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

I have Classroom model Like:

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :students,dependent: :destroy
end
```

I have Student model Like:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :classroom, optional: true
    validate :check_student_limit
    def check_student_limit
        if Student.where(classroom_id: self.classroom_id).count > 4
            self.errors.add(:name, "Over limit of student in classroom")
        end
    end
end
```

Classroom `has_many` student so 
I want to update the selected students classroom.

Suppose I have a classroom with id: 4.
Now I select the three students of that classroom which has an id (14,15,16) and I also select the id in which class I want to move these three students. Let's say I want to move these three students in Classroom_id: 5, 
These three students should move into the classroom 5, and three students delete from classroom 4.

I create a new form for selecting passed students and a new classroom for those students.
In my action controller for this form 
I get the selected `students_ids` and new classroom id

But now I'm stuck here.
How can I insert all these selected students into the selected classroom?
I'm troubling here to solve this, please help me if you can.

Here the Images for the reference.

This is  how can I selected the students and new classrooms:
[image: This is how can I selected the students and new classrooms]

I got the following params in the console:
[image: I got the following params in console]

Comment: Can you add the respective controller code and be specific about what error you are getting while doing so ? It will be helpful

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682951/rails-4-nested-form-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-controller-setup) as an example.

Comment: I want to insert the selected students  to selected classroom.
 
and I also want to delete the students of previous classroom.

How can i do this ???

Comment: I already have one form for creating new classroom In classroom controller

Answer (score 1):

**Advice:** You have written too much about your issue which means many people may skip for reason TLDR.

Your real issue is that you have an array of `student` ids and a new `classroom` id but you are stuck with how to update them at once i.e. add to new classroom and remove from previous.

You can achieve that by simply changing their `classroom_id` from `x` to `y` in the controller action that you are posting to:

```
  def update_class
    Student.where(id: params[:student_ids]).update_all(classroom_id: 5)
    # This will move them to classroom 5 and remove from classroom 4.
  end
```

You only need to use update_all. If there is more to this issue, comment below and I will update the answer.

Comment: This is work with me.
Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: @bhadreshChotaliya glad I could help. Can you please accept the answer and upvote? Thanks.

Comment: can you help me to solve this ??
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59987284/12594070

Comment: @bhadreshChotaliya you should accept this answer and upvote if it helped you. I will have a look into your other question, of course.